# Trouble Finding Least Common Multiple of Numbers 1-20

Tags: python, math, number-theory, lcm

```
"""5. 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"""
list=[]
possibility_list=[]
base=1
numberlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for number in numberlist:
    for iteration in range(1000):
        list.append(iteration*number)
for possibility in list:
    if list.count(possibility)==20:
        print("Found LCM of [1:21] -->", str(possibility))
        possibility_list.append(possibility)
    else: continue
print(min(possibility_list))
```

I am currently trying to solve Euler Problem #5, which wants to find the LCM of numbers 1-20. The code above is brute force, but for some reason it doesn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

As of python 3.9 you can compute the [least common multiple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) directly:

```
from math import lcm

print(lcm(*range(1, 11)))
```

If that's "cheating", start with a loop like this:

```
from math import lcm

result = 1
for i in range (1, 11):
    result = lcm(result, i)
```

Then replace `lcm` with [`gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd). The two-arg version of `gcd` (greatest common divisor) has been around since python 3.5:

```
from math import gcd

result = 1
for i in range (1, 11):
    result *= i // gcd(result, i)
```

Now `gcd` is something that's relatively easy to implement using Euclid's algorithm. The idea is that if the GCD of two numbers `x` and `y` is `g`, then `x = a * g` and `y = b * g`, with `a`, `b` relatively prime. If `a` and `b` weren't relatively prime, you could divide them by their common multiple and multiply `g` by that amount. Let's say `a >= b`. If `x` is a multiple of `y`, `b` must be 1 (again, `a` and `b` are relatively prime) and therefore `y = g`. Otherwise, `c = a - b` must be relatively prime to both `a` and `b` (else they *all* have a common factor). We can therefore repeat the same reasoning for `y` and `z = x - y` until the two numbers become multiples of each other. The sequence must converge because the numbers decrease with every subtraction:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    if x < y:
        x, y = y, x
    if x % y == 0:
        return y
    return gcd(x - y, y)

result = 1
for i in range (1, 11):
    result *= i // gcd(result, i)
```

You can probably make this more efficient, but this should be sufficient to form an understanding of how to solve the problem.

A non-recursive GCD might be advisable in the general case, since python supports arbitrary sized integers. You could implemented it as

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while True:
        if x < y:
            x, y = y, x
        if x % y == 0:
            return y
        x -= y
```

Even if you're going to use brute force, I suggest that you do it with a little more intelligence. For example, you know that `10 < lcm <= 1 * 2 * ... * 9 * 10` you can therefore write your check like this:

```
numbers = range(1, 11)
product = 1
for i in numbers:
    product *= i
for n in range(max(numbers) + 1, product + 1):
    for i in numbers:
        if n % i != 0:
            break
    else:
        break
print(n)
```

The inner loop checks the current possibility against all the `numbers`. If the loop terminates without breaking, `n` is a multiple of all the numbers. This triggers the `else` clause, which breaks out of the outer loop. The result is guaranteed to be correct because if nothing breaks the loop, `n` will be the multiple of all the numbers.

In all the above cases, it's trivial to include the range [1, 20] in place of [1, 10].

Answer (score 1):

```py
numberlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]


def is_prime(num: int) -> bool:
    for factor in range(2, num):
        if num % factor == 0:
            return False
    return True


prime_list = list(filter(is_prime, numberlist))
additional_factor_prime = []
for number in numberlist:
    temp_factor_list = [*prime_list] + additional_factor_prime
    temp_number = number
    for index in range(len(temp_factor_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        if temp_number in prime_list:
            break
        cur_factor = temp_factor_list[index]
        if temp_number % cur_factor == 0:
            temp_factor_list.pop(index)
            temp_number //= cur_factor
    if temp_number not in temp_factor_list and temp_number != 0 and temp_number != 1:
        additional_factor_prime.append(temp_number)

factor_list = [*prime_list] + additional_factor_prime
LCM = 1
for number in factor_list:
    LCM *= number
print(LCM)
```